# Not getting the single product data from products.js while using express

Tags: reactjs, express

Here is my server.js file where the routes are created using express.

```
const express = require('express');
const products = require('./data/products');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json('Api is running succesfully...');
});

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(products);
});

app.get('/api/product/:id', (req, res) => {
  const product = products.find((x) => x._id === req.params.id);
  res.json(product);
});

app.listen(5000, console.log('server is running at port 5000'));
```

So I have used following in the products.js file to export it:

```
module.exports = products;
```

The problem is i get the products data when i go to the route localhost:5000/api/products but when i go to route localhost:5000/api/product/1 i dont get anything when i console logged the req.params.id it gives the id number which i have in the route i.e 1 but when i logged product it gives me undefined. Please help me why i am not getting single product??

Comment: can you please provide the request of `/api/product/:id` and json of products

Comment: or try `products.find((x) => x._id.toString() === req.params.id.toString());`

Comment: Got it man i did products.find((x) => x._id === Number(req.params.id))

Comment: But why do I sometimes have to add Number and sometimes I dont need that req.params.id to be converted to number. I dont understand that part.

Comment: You will always get a string from `req.params` even if its number

Comment: So like when i used this before it didn't need to be converted to number but nowadays without converting to Number it goes undefined. Is it because of changes made by node.js dev's?

Comment: You are getting `undefined` because when `find` function will not find anything that will return always `undefined`. About the Node thing then it's wrong, `req.params` keys always return a string in old version also.

Comment: Like i dont want to extend too much. But MERN course of Brad traversy in udemy uses only products.find((x) => x._id === match.params.id) he doesnt convert the params to number but in his case it works. But in my case it doesnt even if i do the exact same code. Thats just making me confused why not working in my case.

Comment: Please check in your course, `_id` will be a string or brad used `==` instead of `===`. BTW Brad traversy is great instructor.

Comment: yeah maybe i think _id is string in his case. Yeah his courses has been giving me so much for 6 months. Learning react and other stuffs I love his content he is only reason i have this much progress.

Comment: Ofcourse u were great frnd to talk too also with help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express always return a string in `req.params.<VAR>`, so if you are sure that you will get the Number from the `params` then convert the string to the number by `parseInt` or `+`.

**Convert All To Number**

```
products.find((x) => +x._id === +req.params.id);
```

**Convert All to String**

```
products.find((x) => x._id.toString() === req.params.id.toString());
```